# Once working wireless card has completely disappeard

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

I have been using Ubuntu for over a year now on my mid 2010 Macbook pro. I successfully installed proprietary drivers for a Broadcom wireless device and never had any issues with wifi.

After upgrading to 18.04 the wifi worked just fine. Then, one day, it just didn't.

Results of iwconfig are as follows:

```
enp0s10   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig:

```
enp0s10: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::53da:4624:3774:bd2c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:25:4b:c3:b2:4a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27922  bytes 29137649 (29.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21190  bytes 2564310 (2.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2802  bytes 276338 (276.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2802  bytes 276338 (276.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

sudo lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8403 Apple, Inc. Internal Memory Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05ac:8213 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:8507 Apple, Inc. Built-in iSight
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05ac:0236 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

sudp lshw -C network:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: MCP79 Ethernet
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: a
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
       logical name: enp0s10
       version: b1
       serial: 00:25:4b:c3:b2:4a
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.13 latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 memory:d3586000-d3586fff ioport:21e0(size=8) memory:d3589000-d35890ff memory:d3589300-d358930f
```

sudo rfkill list:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

sudo lspci -nn:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Host Bridge [10de:0a82] (rev b1)
00:00.1 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller [10de:0a88] (rev b1)
00:03.0 ISA bridge [0601]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 LPC Bridge [10de:0aae] (rev b3)
00:03.1 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller [10de:0aa4] (rev b1)
00:03.2 SMBus [0c05]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 SMBus [10de:0aa2] (rev b1)
00:03.3 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller [10de:0a89] (rev b1)
00:03.4 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Memory Controller [10de:0a98] (rev b1)
00:03.5 Co-processor [0b40]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Co-processor [10de:0aa3] (rev b1)
00:04.0 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller [10de:0aa5] (rev b1)
00:04.1 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller [10de:0aa6] (rev b1)
00:06.0 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller [10de:0aa7] (rev b1)
00:06.1 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller [10de:0aa9] (rev b1)
00:08.0 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 High Definition Audio [10de:0ac0] (rev b1)
00:09.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Bridge [10de:0aab] (rev b1)
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Ethernet [10de:0ab0] (rev b1)
00:0b.0 SATA controller [0106]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 AHCI Controller [10de:0ab9] (rev b1)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge [10de:0ac4] (rev b1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge [10de:0aa0] (rev b1)
00:15.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge [10de:0ac6] (rev b1)
00:16.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 PCI Express Bridge [10de:0ac7] (rev b1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C79 [GeForce 9400M] [10de:0863] (rev b1)
05:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller [11c1:5901] (rev 07)
```

cat wireless-info.txt:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 20 Nov 2019 19:40 PST -0800

Booted last: 20 Nov 2019 00:00 PST -0800

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.0.0-36-generic #39~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 11:09:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

GNOME on Xorg

##### lspci #############################

00:0a.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP79 Ethernet [10de:0ab0] (rev b1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Apple iMac 9,1 [10de:cb79]
    Kernel driver in use: forcedeth

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8403 Apple, Inc. Internal Memory Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05ac:8213 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:8507 Apple, Inc. Built-in iSight
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05ac:0236 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

This system doesn't support Secure Boot

##### lsmod #############################

mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    28672  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s10' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s10
       valid_lft 82830sec preferred_lft 82830sec
    inet6 fe80::53da:4624:3774:bd2c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.7.0.2/24 brd 10.7.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::77f3:43f5:d857:222a/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp0s10   no wireless extensions.

tun0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.0.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s10 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.7.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.0.2 
104.140.14.58 via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s10 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.0.1 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s10 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s10 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.13 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       874     1  0 18:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s10
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         NVIDIA Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        MCP79 Ethernet (Apple iMac 9,1)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         forcedeth
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 0.64
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s10' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0a.0/net/enp0s10
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s10
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       c10bab60-1b82-3605-ba19-c237b90d8f1a
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.13/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 104.140.14.58/32, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 0
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.13
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1574390435
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::53da:4624:3774:bd2c/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   c10bab60-1b82-3605-ba19-c237b90d8f1a | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         tun0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceTun
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tun
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.6
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       tun0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     tun0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       40a8300e-9fdd-4475-84e9-54752a5f8caa
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.7.0.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.7.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/1, nh = 10.7.0.1, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 128.0.0.0/1, nh = 10.7.0.1, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::77f3:43f5:d857:222a/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   40a8300e-9fdd-4475-84e9-54752a5f8caa | tun0

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Los_Angeles (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp0s10   no frequency information.

tun0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

Sorry, try again.
enp0s10   Interface doesn't support scanning.

tun0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   71.883033] forcedeth 0000:00:0a.0 enp0s10: MSI enabled
[   71.883843] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s10: link becomes ready
[  236.121550] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvac_fuc084 failed with error -2
[  236.121563] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvac_fuc084d failed with error -2
[  236.121565] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data

########## wireless info END ############
```

This is an internal Broadcom wireless card.

After an entire day of troubleshooting I decided to wipe my computer and install 16.04, seeing as I had no trouble beforehand. Surprisingly, this didn't fix the issue. Have since upgraded back to 18.04.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Is this an internal wireless card, or a USB wireless dongle? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them. Report back.

Comment: Also show me `sudo lspci -nn`.

Comment: thanks @heynnema the question has been edited

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Your `sudo lspci -nn` command didn't come out right. Maybe you can try it again for me. Also show me `dkms status`.

Comment: Your results show me no installed Broadcom driver, and no installed Broadcom wireless device. Sounds like a hardware problem. If you're brave enough, I'd open your MacBook Pro and reseat the wireless/bluetooth card, and see if things start to work again.

Comment: Reboot your computer, select grub's Advanced Options for Ubuntu menu option. Then pick an earlier kernel version to boot.

Comment: thanks @heynnema. reseated Broadcom wireless card and still no change. strangely, bluetooth works. I thought these were the same card? If you're up for it, I've just included results of wireless-info.txt in my question. Does this provide a definitive answer?

Comment: @mike_munro Did you ever show me `dkms status`? Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? If so, boot it, and see if it finds a wireless card. You may or may not need to install Broadcom drivers for it. lspci and lsusb can be used.

Comment: @heynnema - dkms status doesn't return anything at all. When I previously installed 16.04 I only needed to check 'install proprietary drivers.' It was very easy to do. What's strange about this is everything was working just fine before failure (including in 18.04). Will boot my live USB next to see if wifi is detected.

Answer (score 0):

I like to test the possibility of a hardware failure if a device that always worked properly before suddenly stops working. If my mouse or keyboard doesn't work I usually try plugging it in to another computer. If a hardware device that I can't plug in to another computer like a wireless adapter doesn't work, I try booting to a live session with an Ubuntu live USB. I also take a photo of the boot messages screen, and study it to see if I can find anything interesting about a possible hardware problem there. If there is a hardware problem with RAM stick, it will almost always get printed on the screen when the computer is booting.